# Possible to cancel curl HTTP PUT from server?

Tags: c, apache, rest, curl, cgi

I have a CGI program written in C that reads a PUT request from curl on the client and copies the uploaded file to a directory on the server. This all works fine.

The problem is, I need a way of cancelling the upload in progress if there's a problem, for example if the user's storage has been exceeded. I can't seem to do this by simply returning from the CGI program. curl continues to try to upload the file, so on large files I have to wait for it to send the entire file (or thinks it's sending the entire file) before it will read the server response that tells it "no."

Is there a way to quit the CGI program and terminate the connection without having to wait for the PUT request to complete?

**UPDATE**

Per carminati's suggestion, I created another CGI program that contains only the following:

```
int main(void){
    printf("Status: 413 Request Entity Too Large\r\n\r\n"
    //"Status: 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n"
    "Hi, CGI program here. I'm out.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

However, curl on the client seems to either not receive or ignore any server response until the PUT operation is completed. I do get the response after the PUT is completed, but this isn't acceptable as the PUT can go on for several minutes with a large file before any error is detected.

I also tried disabling mod_deflate and restarting Apache, but this made no difference.

At this point, it seems like Apache is refusing to send anything back to the client until it reads the PUT in its entirety. This is a real problem, especially with large files. If the CGI program determines early in the upload that there's a problem, the server needs to tell the client to **stop sending data right now.** I just can't figure out any way to do this.

Comment: For Apache, if the url you're trying is not found, curl will end immediately. That means curl has the ability to terminate early, but (if the url is found) Apache waits for the file to finish before sending a termination notice.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but I tested some other things. I created a file 3G in size, then used Apache with php: the php script started running soon after the request started, then called `die()`, but Apache doesn't care that `die()` has been called, it just keeps waiting for the file to finish. I also tried Express (not Apache) with set timeout for 15s to call request.end(): curl immediately stops after around 15s. So, the conclusion is that the server can make curl stop halfway; your issue has to do with how Apache works. Not sure if there is a config for this.

Comment: This seems related: [Connection not closed when CGI dies waiting ...](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50948) but it's a very old page.

Comment: Here I found some [source code in C](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c) for `fastcgi_finish_request` in php. Not sure if this is relevant, though.

Comment: @qrsngky Thanks for trying curl with Express. Would you mind posting your curl command? It sounds like curl is definitely capable of cancelling an upload (if told properly), I just need to figure out how to get Apache to do it.

Comment: I ran the curl tests from WSL/Ubuntu, so I created a file like `fallocate -l 3G fake_file1` and sent it like `curl -X PUT $(hostname).local:80/some_test.php --upload-file ./fake_file1`

Comment: I just re-tested with `-I` like `curl -I -X put $(hostname).local:80/some_test.php --upload-file ./fake_file1`, and saw that Apache immediately responded with `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` and I only saw the replacement header (413) from php only much later. However, for `some_wrong_url.php`, I immediately saw `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

Comment: That's the same thing I'm seeing with my C program. BTW, you can tell curl not to ask for the continue (potentially saving 1 sec if the server doesn't respond) by passing -H "Expect:". This will eliminate that step altogether, just to simplify troubleshooting. I tried this and it still doesn't work: Apache flat out ignores everything else until the POST/PUT completes, which is extremely frustrating and puzzling behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there many are ways to cancel the upload in progress from the server-side without waiting for the PUT request to complete.

One way to do this is by sending an HTTP error code to the client while the file is being uploaded. When the client receives the error code, it will stop the upload process immediately. To achieve this, you can use the standard C library function printf to output the appropriate HTTP error code and message. For example, to send a "413 Request Entity Too Large" error to the client, you can do:

```
printf("Status: 413 Request Entity Too Large\r\n\r\n");

fflush(stdout);
```

The fflush call is needed to ensure that the message is sent to the client immediately, without waiting for the end of the request.

Another way to cancel the upload is to use the setsockopt function to set the SO_LINGER option on the socket to a non-zero value before exiting the CGI program. This will cause the TCP connection to be closed immediately, aborting the upload process. Here's an example:

```
struct linger linger = {1, 0};

setsockopt(fileno(stdout), SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &linger,

sizeof(linger));

exit(0);
```

This sets the SO_LINGER option to a struct linger with a timeout of 1 second, which means that the socket will linger for up to 1 second after the close call until all pending data has been sent or the timeout has expired.

Note that the second approach may not work on all systems, as some TCP/IP stacks may ignore the SO_LINGER option when the socket is in a non-blocking state (which is often the case for CGI programs). The first approach is generally more reliable, but may require more coordination between the CGI program and the client.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but curl ignores any server response until it finishes its upload (or at least until it reads the entire file). See my updated question.

Comment: @Synthetix: I think it's Apache that ignores the fact that your script had ended. If it sends a response that makes curl stop early, then curl will stop early. (Such as the case when the URL is not found)

Comment: @qrsngky I think you're right, but I tried writing a Status: 413 to stdout (and flushing stdout) before terminating the program. The expected behavior would be for curl to see this before having to wait for the PUT upload to complete.